# WPF button OnPreviewMouseUp and OnPreviewMouseDown behave differently

Tags: wpf, button

I'm experimenting the OnPreviewMouseUp and OnPreviewMouseDown tunneling events. I'm particularly interested in ***e.OriginalSource*** as I don't understand why when I click on the text content of the button, e.OriginalSource is still the button itself, and not the text block - the visual child of the button.  In fact I found the OnPreviewMouseDown event does do what I expected -- it shows e.OriginalSource as text block, however the OnPreviewMouseUp event always shows e.OriginalSource as the button itself.  The following is the simple code I used for this experiment:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Margin="5">
  <Button Name="cmd" Margin="8">Click me.</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class ButtonMouseUpEvent : System.Windows.Window
{

    public ButtonMouseUpEvent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
        Debug.WriteLine($"OnPreviewMouseDown(): e.Source = {e.Source}, e.OriginalSource = {e.OriginalSource}");
    }


    protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);
        Debug.WriteLine($"OnPreviewMouseUp(): e.Source = {e.Source}, e.OriginalSource = {e.OriginalSource}");
    }
```

I suspect this has something to do with button's click event, which eats up the MouseUp event, but I'm trying to understand exactly why.

Comment: You suspect correctly.
If you right-click, the TextBlock will be the event source for both events.
To understand why, you have to understand the source codes of the button.
How much do you need it?

Comment: Is it really that complicated? You can see in buttonbase that it handles click and raises a new event.  Quite frankly, I've never felt the need to bottom this out but looks to me like this is the reason for the behaviour you're seeing.  
httpss://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,1001a15c43ab91f9